# Storing nested documents in elasticsearch which may have nullable fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch for indexing in my application. I'm trying to store a document which in turn contains a field of a custom data structure:

```
@Document(indexName="sampleIndex", type="user")
class User {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Person person;
}

class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

I'm using`ElasticsearchRepository` to save this entity. There are chances that `lastName` or `firstName` of the `Person` may be null. In this case I get a `NullPointerException` on calling `repository.save(entity)`. Is there a way to suppress this? Because I still want to save this on elasticsearch irrespective of whether some of the fields are null or not.